# Collatz's First Conjecture

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, integer, natural-language

### Background

The Collatz Conjecture is quite well-known. Take any natural number. Triple and increment if odd; cut in half if even. Repeat, and it will reach 1 eventually. This famous conjecture, however, is only that, for it is yet unproven.

Little-known to the world, that was not Lothar Collatz's first attempt at fame. His first Conjecture (now proven) was a touch simpler:

- Take any natural number *n*.
- While *n* ≠ 4, find the length of its written-out form (English). Store this value to *n*.

The conjecture is that all natural numbers will eventually become 4. This did not catch on as well as Collatz had hoped, so he returned to the drawing board.

### Your task

Read a positive integer *n* < 2147483648 (2^31) from input and return/print the number of iterations required to reach 4.

### Things to note

Do not use *and*. 228 is "two hundred twenty-eight," **not** "two hundred and twenty-eight."

Do not use articles. 145 is "one hundred forty-five," not "a hundred forty-five.)

Commas set apart each three orders or magnitude: "one million, four hundred eighty-two thousand, one hundred seventy-five."

Punctuation is counted. Spaces are not. Hyphenate 21-99 except multiples of ten.

### Test cases

> 4 (four): **0**
>   3 (three→five→four): **2**
>   6278 (six thousand, two hundred seventy-eight→thirty-five→eleven→six→three→five→four): **6**
>   1915580 (one million, nine hundred fifteen thousand, five hundred eighty→fifty-five→ten→three→five→four): **5**
>   2147483647 (two billion, one hundred forty-seven million, four hundred eighty-three thousand, six hundred forty-seven→ninety-three→twelve→six→three→five→four): **6**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code (in bytes) in each language WINS! Good luck!

Comment: `one million, nine hundred fifteen thousand, five hundred eighty` is of length `63`, not `55`. The correct result for `1915580` is `6`, not `5`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `Punctuation is counted. Spaces are not`

Comment: @H.PWiz Thanks for letting me know, I fixed my answer.

Comment: Do numbers above `10^66` need to be handled?

Comment: No, will edit soon to address this.

Comment: [Four has Four Letters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKn0yUTIU4&index=287&list=LLKVu39bD7-2d_AIyRdAfG-g)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [inflect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect),  <s>122</s>  114 bytes

Saved 8 bytes thanks to [Scrooble](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/scrooble).

```python
from inflect import*
f=lambda k,i=0:k!=4and f(len(engine().number_to_words(k,andword="").replace(" ","")),i+1)or i
```

This cannot be tested online because of the package it uses. Running the test suite gives:

```
4 -> 0
3 -> 2
6278 -> 6
1915580 -> 5
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with inflect, but from reading the linked page, I believe that this could be shortened by using `number_to_words(k,andword="")` instead of `number_to_words(k).replace(" and","")` (saves 8 bytes).